# Migration of code from AngularJS to ReactJS

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, react-hooks

I am migrating my AngularJS website into ReactJS. I am new to React , so I am not much known to the background details of it. I have some classes that extends Injectables. But as React does not have dependency injections, how to treat them in React. I have some lines of code in AngularJS and want to convert it in ReactJS. What will be the strategy to do it?

```
class myClass extends Injectable {
  $fetch(entities, resolveExtraContexts) {
    const { $uibResolve, $q } = this.getServices(['$uibResolve', '$q']);
    ...
    });
  }
}

const fetcher = new myClass();
...

export default abc;
```

Here I do not know how to pass promises instead of $q . Also, what is the replacement of classes that extends Injectable. Last, but not the least, this.getServices just queues up all the dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) and apply your api service logic there:

```
componentDidMount() {
  // ... fetch
  this.setState({fetchedData })
```

---

Now, strict to your question.

React has no dependency injection concept. And you may find this [medium blog](https://medium.com/@maxheiber/no-need-for-dependency-injection-in-react-components-641182760aaa) helpful.

If you want to apply injection logic in react, then you may use [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html). And you may find this [medium blog](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/reactjs-hoc-how-to-inject-dependencies-to-react-component-in-angularjs-way-a2fc63d795c8)  helpful. The following code extracted from the linked blog:

```
function withApiService (WrappedComponent) {
  class HOC extends React.Component {
    render () {
      const key = this.props.apiKey;
      const apiService = new ApiService({key});

      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          {...this.props}
          apiService={apiService}
        />
      );
    }
  }
  return HOC;
}
```

Comment: So, depending on my code, how should I draft code in ReactJS. If you can guide me through this example, it will be of great help.